# Tensorflow Lite: Check Failed when converting with Toco

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to convert my frozen inference model to .tflite using the following command in toco.

```
toco\
--graph_def_file=frozen_inference_graph.pb \
--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
--output_format=TFLITE \
--output_file=/leaves.tflite \
--inference_type=FLOAT \
--input_type=FLOAT \
--input_arrays=ImageTensor \
--output_arrays=SemanticPredictions \
--input_shapes=1,513,513,3 \
```

But I am getting an error

```
RuntimeError: TOCO failed see console for info.
b'2019-03-06 15:28:46.912978: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1080] Converting unsupported operation: ResizeNearestNeighbor
2019-03-06 15:28:46.956622: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before Removing unused ops: 1790 operators, 2758 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-03-06 15:28:47.000274: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] After Removing unused ops pass 1: 1780 operators, 2739 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-03-06 15:28:47.059984: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before general graph transformations: 1780 operators, 2739 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-03-06 15:28:47.261502: F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/propagate_fixed_sizes.cc:624] Check failed: input_shape.dims().size() == op->size.size() (4 vs. 3)\nAborted (core dumped)\n'
None
```

From what I understand the 4 in "(4 vs. 3)" refers to the 4 dimensions my input_shapes 1,513,513,3.  But having searched around no one seems to have had the same error so I am unsure what is causing this problem.

Is anyone able to identify the problem and provide a solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"toco" is kind of deprecated. Could you try "tflite_convert" as detailed in https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/cmdline_examples?

Comment: If `tflite_convert` does not work with you, please file a [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) on the TensorFlow GitHub page. Include all of the steps to reproduce your problem including your model file or a minimal model that reproduces your error.